# Email Verification Link in Laravel 7 gives "Error Unknown named parameter $id" when clicked

Tags: php, laravel

[screenshot of Error Unknown named parameter $id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev1fY.png)

I'm using Laravel 7. I've successfully registered a user. The verification email has been successfully sent to my mailtrap inbox as expected. But when I click on the "Verify Email Address" button or the URL provided down there in the email, it gives me the above error. Kindly assist, please.
Thank you.

This is my HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

}
```

This is my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    //return view('myhome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated my composer.json and that fixed it for me.
`composer update`

Answer (score 0):

I had my PHP version in 8.0, changing to 7.4 fixed the error.

`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4`